# Static ip setting fails

Tags: networking, server

I'm trying to set up a fresh install of ubuntu server as a home server.
The static ip setting fails somehow, it's still getting a dynamic ip from my router.
I'm trying to use an usb ethernet device (enx00909e9aa057).

Output from ip link show:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d0:50:99:9a:0d:f3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: enx00909e9aa057: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:90:9e:9a:a0:57 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Here is my /etc/network/interfaces file:

```
# The loopback interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#usb ethernet
auto enx00909e9aa057
iface enx00909e9aa057 inet static
   address 192.168.0.26
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   gateway 192.168.0.1
   dns-nameservers 1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1
```

What could be the cause?

edit: if I set my router's DHCP pool start address to something higher, like 192.168.0.150 (it was 192.168.0.10...), the sever will get that address (192.168.0.150). So the problem is not, that the address which I'm setting in the server, is inside the DHCP pool of the router.

Comment: Is this server 17.10? Netplan covers networking by default in 17.10 and later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[chili555](https://askubuntu.com/users/19421/chili555) gave a very good hint (thanks!), netplan was overriding all my settings.
I've followed [this](https://websiteforstudents.com/configuring-static-ips-ubuntu-17-10-servers/) tutorial to set it up, and now it works.